# How to compare current list index with the next list index using lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

So basically im doing a uni assignment where i have to use High order functions in Python. I ran into a problem where i want to iterate over a list to calculate the distance between 2 points using a formula but i dnt know how to access the next value of the list within the lambda function . Can any1 find a away to do it?

```
cidades = {'Lisboa': (38.7452, -9.1604), 
           'Vila Nova de Gaia': (41.1333, -8.6167),
           'Porto': (41.1495, -8.6108),
           'Braga': (41.5333, -8.4167),
           'Matosinhos': (41.2077, -8.6674),
           'Amadora': (38.75, -9.2333),
           'Almada': (38.6803, -9.1583),
           'Oeiras': (38.697, -9.3017),
           'Gondomar': (41.15, -8.5333),
           'Guimarães': (41.445, -8.2908),
           'Odivelas': (38.8, -9.1833),
           'Coimbra': (40.2111, -8.4291),
           'Vila Franca de Xira': (38.95, -8.9833),
           'Maia': (41.2333, -8.6167),
           'Leiria': (39.7431, -8.8069),
           'Setúbal': (38.5243, -8.8926),
           'Viseu': (40.6667, -7.9167),
           'Valongo': (41.1833, -8.5),
           'Viana do Castelo': (41.7, -8.8333),
           'Paredes': (41.2, -8.3333),
           'Vila do Conde': (41.35, -8.75),
           'Torres Vedras': (39.0833, -9.2667),
           'Barreiro': (38.6609, -9.0733),
           'Aveiro': (40.6389, -8.6553),
           'Queluz': (38.7566, -9.2545),
           'Mafra': (38.9333, -9.3333),
           'Penafiel': (41.2, -8.2833),
           'Loulé': (37.144, -8.0235)}

distancia_ponto_ponto = lambda origem,destino :math.sqrt( ( (((cidades.get(destino)[0] - cidades.get(origem)[0]) * 111.1949) ** 2) + (((cidades.get(destino)[1] - cidades.get(origem)[1]) * 85.1102) ** 2)))
```

Since it is a "simple" math formula i dnt find any trouble to do the first function yet if i want to use it over a list to iterate the list and make this calcs between the current index and the next one i cant find a way. To exemplify wht i wanna i do ill do it with a for yet i must use High order functions for this assignment

```
itin = ['Maia' , 'Barreiro','Paredes','Queluz']

def distancia_itinerario(itin ): 
    lat = 111.1949
    longi = 85.1102
    count = 0
     
    for a in range(0, len(itin )):
        if a+1 < len(itin ):

            x= ((cidades.get(itin [a+1])[0] -cidades.get(itin [a])[0]) * lat)**2
            
            y=((cidades.get(itin [a+1])[1] -cidades.get(itin [a])[1])  * longi)**2

            count += math.sqrt(x+y)

    return count
```

Comment: Your code works. Please explain your issue more detailed (you are talking about functions and lists, but not which ones).

Comment: what im asking is how do i convert my distancia_itinerario function into a lambda function since i cant find a way to get the next index(a+1) in lambda

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this lambda code below? It's a bit lengthy but it seems to work for me. The code is pretty similar to the function, I just change the iteration instead from 0 to `len(itin) - 1` to be from 0 to `len(tin) - 2` since you don't need to do anything when `a` is `len(ti) - 1`

```
dist_lambda = lambda itin: sum(math.sqrt((((cidades.get(itin[a+1])[0] -cidades.get(itin [a])[0]) * 111.1949)**2)+(((cidades.get(itin [a+1])[1] -cidades.get(itin [a])[1])  * 85.1102)**2)) for a in range(len(itin) - 1))

itin = ['Maia' , 'Barreiro','Paredes','Queluz']
print(dist_lambda(itin))
```

Edit: If you don't want to use `for` or `while` loop then I think you can use `zip(itin, itin[1:])` instead to pair each consecutive items in `itin` together as a tuple (in this case the output of `zip(itin, itin[1:])` would be `[('Maia', 'Barreiro'), ('Barreiro', 'Paredes'), ('Paredes', 'Queluz')])` and then apply the lambda function `distancia_ponto_ponto` to each item in the list using `map` function, which will return a list of distance from each pair and then sum them up using `sum` function

```
distancia_ponto_ponto = lambda origem,destino :math.sqrt( ( (((cidades.get(destino)[0] - cidades.get(origem)[0]) * 111.1949) ** 2) + (((cidades.get(destino)[1] - cidades.get(origem)[1]) * 85.1102) ** 2)))
distance = sum(map(distancia_itinerario, zip(itin, itin[1:])))
print(distance)
```

Comment: it does work yet it uses a for loop inside the lambda and thts exactly what i am struggling with . I was not supposed to use any for/while loop and i didnt find a way to do it without one @user696969

Comment: @Nando Ok I've updated my answer with an alternatives to using loop. Is that the expected solution?